# How to add display-output-escaping= "yes" in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, elements-xml

I am a fresh Share point worker.
I made up a workflow to create item in List, and it works. After Creating in Word Fields, it has  in both side of rich text. I wanted to add display-output-escaping= "yes". when I insert the Text to the view in Designer, it does not work.
I insert in XML and XML definition and I tried in different parts. 
please help me to find the way to fix the problem.

Comment: How did you inserted rich text fields? Which version of SharePoint are you using? what do you mean when inserting text to view in designer are you trying to use SharePoint designer ?

Comment: Hi, I am using SharePoint 2010 Server and I am not the main owner but have Full control and my own site. yes, I am trying to use Share-point designer.  I did following issues: I have a workflow on a list, which transfer specific fields to a template word library and recreate it there in word. What is the problem? EX: if I have this sentence in List: World Community,  I see in word as : <div> word community <div> and if there  would be highlight or ... the code will become more. I found that I should make some changes in main view code, but where?

Comment: As per my understanding you are trying to create a word document using the list fields with workflow??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working in a data view created in SharePoint Designer. If so, I would start by right clicking (in design veiw) on one of the rich text areas, select Format Item As, and see if any of those formats get your desired results. More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/09/20/using-disable-output-escaping-in-data-view.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer, I was totally disappointed but you have changed it, thank you and I will check your answer as soon as possible. and will tell you more